# Remove or delete old data from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

> How to remove old data from elastic search index as the index has large amount of data being inserted every day.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 23):

You can do that with [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html) plugin.

Assuming you have some `timestamp` or `creation date` field in your index, your query would look something like this

```
DELETE /your_index/your_type/_query
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "lte": "now-10y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will delete records older than 10 years.

I hope this helps

Comment: Is there any way to do it in the form of a script so we don't have to run the query manually

Comment: Does this delete query erase the records completely from the index and allow space for new records to be inserted

Comment: You can set up a `cron job` to do it daily, records are **not** erased after you perform delete, they are **marked** as deleted and during segment merging they are actually removed, you might see increase in index size after deletion or update, you can use [force merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html) to optimize your index

Comment: What is segment merging ? After segment merging is the size of index decreased

Comment: go through [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html) to understand segment merging, you cant decrease size like that, just deleted data wont be there after merging segments. Also [read](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up) about how elasticsearch works to have better understanding.

Answer (score 12):

Split data to daily indexes and use alias as old index name. then Delete the each index daily. just as logstash:

Daily indices :`logstash-20151011`,`logstash-20151012`,`logstash-20151013`.

Full Alias: logstash

Then daily delete last index.

Comment: Using multiple indexes is the way to go. To delete the older indexes you could use curator: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using time-based indices, that should be something like:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/test-2017-06
```